# Django - Edit User Form and Profile Form To change Information and User Profile Picture

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So In my Django Admin I have a User section (that comes default) and I made a profile section in my forms.py file. I want to add an option when you click in the profile page to redirect to and 'edit' profile page where a user can change their user/profile info including their picture. I'm still pretty knew to Django so I don't know where I need to begin. I have snippets of my code from different parts of my Django app to show because currently I don't know where to start.

**Models.py File:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


# User Profile Model
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followed_by', symmetrical=False, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='static/chat/images/default-profile-photo.jpg', null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/profile/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


# Create Profile When New User Signs Up
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        user_profile = Profile(user=instance)
        user_profile.save()


post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

**fourms.py file:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

**Views.py file:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib import messages
from chat.forms import SignUpForm

# Create your views here.
def chatPage(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('login-user')
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'chat/chatPage.html', context)

def test(request):
    return render(request, 'chat/test-chat.html')

def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ('Registration Successful!'))
            return redirect('chat-page')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'chat/register_user.html', {'form': form})

def profilePage(request):
    return render(request, 'chat/profilePage.html')

def EditProfilePage(request):
    return render(request, 'chat/editProfile.html')
```

My current editprofile.html page is blank at the moment because I know I need to start in other files before working on the html page.